# Why does my cursor keeps getting stuck and starts clicking randomly?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook, mouse-cursor

I have a Samsung Galaxy Chromebook. My cursor keeps being stuck in one place and sometimes it just starts clicking I know that because everything keeps getting selected like when you double or triple-click.
**I searched on google first and it said you can reset(didn't help), press escape multiple times, turn off and on (when I do this it stops being stuck for a movement but then it happens again after some time.), drumroll your fingers, and see if there is dust(i cleaned it thoroughly).**
**Nothing gave a permanent solution**. I am a student and I can't just turn it off and on in the middle of online classes.
**PLEASE HELP ME**

Answer (score 0):

there are many reasons a mousepad can start acting weird. I have one suggestion that might work as this has fixed it for me before.

If you open the computer, most likely there will be some simple connections for the keyboard, storage etc under the battery. Try disconnecting and reconnecting the blue mousepad connection tab. If you have trouble opening the computer, there are plenty of quick tutorials out there. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1JWSnk6uZY.

Comment: So I have to open up my pc? what is the worst that could happen  if I mes up?

Comment: Well the worst realistic thing is that you you unplug the battery or connector and forget to put it back. Just open it up and put them back. If you don't have the proper screwdriver, do not use something else as you can strip the screws.